# POST params are empty in Zend_Rest_Controller

Tags: api, zend-framework, post, zend-rest

I'm using Zend_Rest_Controller to implement a RESTful API.

The GET action works fine, for example when I make the `/user/id/1` request the `:id` parameter is present when I use `$request->getParams()`.

However, when I make a POST request to `/user`, the `postAction()` is called just fine but there is no POST data in `$request->getParams()` or `$request->getPost()`. `$request->getRawBody()` shows that they are getting to the server fine though.

Is there any reason why ZF might not be populating the request object with these params? How do I access them?

Answer (score 0):

Double check the content type on the http headers of the request.  Should be multipart/form-data.

Comment: Thanks @slash28cu the request is coming from backbone.js so the request is application/json, but I just tried it with multipart/form-data from cURL and it's no better.

Comment: Also just tried x-www-form-urlencoded in cURL and that worked fine - is there some way I can specify the API to allow the application/json type request?